# Envio datos formulario Ajax

Tags: ajax, formularios

necesito si me pueden dar una mano sobre este formulario.

finalize ejecuta otras , entre ellas  function ajaxContact

donde en en  se encuentra esta linea url: root_folder + 'tm_contacts/add',
que lo tendría que configurar con mi servidor.

```
  <form >
<input type = "text"id = "name">
</td></tr >
<input value = "Email" type = "text" id = "email" >
<input value = "M&oacute;vil" type = "text" id = "telephone" >
<div>
<a id = "finalize" onclick = "finalize()" > VER PRECIOS < /a> 
 </form>
```

Estas dos lìneas tendría que definirlas en mi servidor

```
 // var root_folder = '/cake_salud/'; 
  var root_folder = '/seguros-salud/comparador/';  


function ajaxContact() {
    var contact = new Object();
    var phone_val = $('#telephone').val();
    // contact['name'] = $('#name').val();
    contact['name'] = '';
    if (phone_val == 'Móvil' || phone_val == 'M&oacute;vil') {
        phone_val = '';
    }
    contact['phone'] = phone_val;
    contact['email'] = $('#email').val();
    contact['comments'] = $('#comments').val();
    contact['wcode'] = wcode;

    contact['rep_ref_code'] = rep_ref_code;
    contact['rep_ctl_code'] = rep_ctl_code;
    contact['rep_s_code'] = rep_s_code;

    // Contacto planeado
    if (outOfTime && typeof($('#daySelectionForm').val()) !=
        'undefined' && typeof($('#hourSelectionForm').val()) !=
        'undefined') {
        contact['plan'] = $('#daySelectionForm').val() + ' ' +
            $('#hourSelectionForm').val();
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: root_folder + 'tm_contacts/add',
        data: contact,
        success: function(data) {
            loaderCerp();
            getResults();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            loaderCerp();
            getResults();
        }
    });
}
```

La consulta es el envio de los datos del formulario por ajax
El formulario tiene varios campos mas y luego devolvería variables, es de una web de comparacion de precios.
Yo solo quiero en primera instancia enviar estos 3 campos, que queden registrados.

Gracias.
Saludos

Comment: Saludos. Le falto agregar el mensaje de error o lo que recibe respecto a lo esperado. Se entiende que se invoca función `finalize` y que esta entre otras tiene la (única que pusiste) `ajaxContact`. Así mismo revisa la idea que quieres plasmar en el párrafo antes del código que proporcionas (no entiendo) para empezar ¿donde tienes definida o valor de `root_folder`?

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, justamente eso quisiera resolver, definir el valor root_folder,. todo se encuentra dentro del mismo archivo .php  y al comienzo estaría difinido asi  // var root_folder = '/cake_salud/';
var root_folder = '/seguros-salud/comparador/';  y /cake_salud/ no se que es, ni tampoco está y debe ser lo que tengo que resolver

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Del lado del cliente (navegador web) todo debe estar definido; o en algún momento inicializarlo con el valor(es) que corresponde(an) si no hay algo como `var root_folder='algunvalor, ruta o algo'` obtendrás `undefined` ya que (digamos) no existe.